# Android Stduio cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

Hello i am facing some weird issues android studio editor show the error
"cannot resolve symbol R" in all the files, but the project is builded and working fine, i can install the app and use it on device "gradle" dont throwing any errors.

i tripple check everything and every thing is fine make sure that every thing updates build clean invlidate cahce infinty times but no solution checked allready all everything releted in stackoverflow but nothing work,

in my project there is 2 modules one is a library and one is app that include this library in the library i have no such error but in app moudle i am getting this error when trying to access resources from app moudle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem was with the R file he simply was to big so he pass the limit of R file size, in order to solve that i needed to increase it by putting this line in the idea.properties file `idea.max.intellisense.filesize=10000`